# Why tcp socket address can be reused immediaely without setting SO_REUSEADDR on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I'm reading Foundations of Python Network Programming and trying the code as follows.

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/fopnp/blob/m/py3/chapter03/tcp_sixteen.py

When commenting the line that turns on socket.SO_REUSEADDR, it raises an OSError on Linux and everything is fine. But on Win8, it behaves like normal even if I explicitly turn off socket.SO_REUSEADDR. Why is this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally one has to use `SO_REUSEADDR` flag, when the Server Socket is in `TIME_WAIT` state. This is a very conservative way of ensuring that any stray data from previous connection(s) doesn't end up being received again by the server and cause confusion as the sequence number may not be same as previous one. Normally probability of that happening is quite low. The timeout for `TIME_WAIT` state is very high (normally 30seconds).

An OS might choose to allow reusing the connection by setting some configuration parameters. eg. in Linux it is `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_*`. [This link](http://www.speedguide.net/articles/linux-tweaking-121) has got details about it.

[this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938217.aspx) has got some details about it for windows. You might want to check what is the value for this. Or if you are opening a large number of connections, likely - the connections a are quickly re-used by Windows without you explicitly needing a `SO_REUSEADDR` as described in the link where the number of available TCB blocks is less.

Comment: Thank you for the links and all those details! I checked the registry but there's no such entry named TcpTimedWaitDelay. Also for test use I open one connection only.

Comment: Which windows version are you using? You might want to start a server stocket - take it through listen -> established -> time_wait state and see whether it remains in time_wait state. I believe windows has `netstat`. Just to see whether the socket is in time_wait state.